# Element ID can't be found after beind appended to DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this bit of jQuery to append a text input field to a div after a checkbox is checked:

```
$('.sharewithfriends').on("click", ".manual-invite", function () {
        if ($('input[name=manual-invite]').is(':checked')) {
          $('<li style="margin-top:0;display:none"><input type="text" id="invite_email1" name="invite-email1" value="Add an E-Mail" onfocus="clearText(invite_email1);" onblur="fillText(invite_email1);"/><span><a class="add" href="">Add</a></span></li>').appendTo('#invite-emails').slideToggle();

}
```

All of that works fine, except for the `onfocus` and `onblur` events. They call the following simple functions, which are supposed to clear the field on focus and fill it with the default text on blur:

```
function clearText(thefield){
if (thefield.defaultValue==thefield.value)
thefield.value = ""
}

function fillText(thefield){
if (thefield.value=="")
thefield.value=thefield.defaultValue;
}
```

But when I click the field, I get an error saying "invite_email1 is not defined" even though it clearly is.

Anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not referring to the right element.

Replace `clearText(invite_email1);` with `clearText(this);`.
Even better, bind event listeners instead of adding inline events.

Comment: Oh, well. Now I feel silly. I had actually tried calling it with (this) at first but got a different unrelated syntax error and switched to calling it with invite_email1. Works now, thanks.